# How to know if some children component of the Root Layout is loading

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm doing an app which has a requirement of showing a loading dot in the navbar while the page changes to another route or it's loading data, but I can't figure out how to do it with the RouterProvider. I tried with the useNavigation but the state is always idle.

Here is my App.tsx where the RouterProvider is

```
import DetailsPage from "@pages/Details"
import EpisodePage from "@pages/Episode"
import HomePage from "@pages/Home"
import RootLayout from "@pages/Root"
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />, // In this component should show the loading dot
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomePage />,
      },
      {
        path: '/podcast/:podcastId',
        element: <DetailsPage />
      },
      {
        path: '/podcast/:podcastId/episode/:episodeId',
        element: <EpisodePage />
      }
    ]
  }
])

const App = () => {

  return <RouterProvider router ={ router } />
}

export default App
```

And my RootLayout component

```
import Navbar from '@components/UI/Navbar'
import { Outlet, useNavigate, useNavigation } from 'react-router-dom'

export const RootLayout = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  return <>
          <Navbar>
            <h1>Podcasters</h1>
            {navigation.state} // Here is where I want to have the dot to show the user it is loading
          </Navbar>
          <Outlet />
        </>
}

export default RootLayout
```

Comment: The router only knows when the route is loading, it knows nothing what the component might be loading ***after*** the route is loaded and the routed component is mounted. What are the routed components fetching once they are mounted? How are those fetches tracked? Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation has three states.

1. Idle
2. submitting
3. loading

So you can track any of those.

for exmaple you can do this:   `{navigation.state !== "idle" && <p>Navigation in progress...</p>}`

Check this official documentation: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation#navigationstate
Or check this example: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/lazy-loading-router-provider/src/App.tsx

Comment: As I commented, I tried using it in the RootLayout element but it always has 'idle' state, it doesn't change while fetching data in the HomePage element or while changing to another path.

Comment: Maybe you are trying from a high end machine so you cannot notice the change. try throtling your network stat in browser developer tools.

Comment: I tried that too and the result it's the same, if I change to Slow it puts loading but it changes to idle way before the fetch functions inside the components finish